# What is reproduce action steps in facebook social reader application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently working on social reader application on facebook, but i am little bit confuse on action steps. In open graph for submit my action, in steps to reproduce your action i don't know what i have to do. In my application i need to click on read button to post my read article to wall.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've to use read action on article/website object.

To create those objects you've to use og meta tags i.e. include some meta tags of this kind:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="URL of this object">
```

Read more: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#article

In app dashboard, under open graph tab, enable read action and article/website object for use.

-- Done configuring --

Let's say you've created the article object at http://mysite.com/path-to-article-I-just-read then following PHP snippet will publish the read action on user's activity feed.

```
// Assuming the app has permission: publis_stream
$facebook->api('/me/news.reads?article=http://mysite.com/path-to-article-I-just-read', 'POST')
```

Once you've completed developing the application, you'll have to submit it for Facebook to review.